# Tracking historical short interest

Tags: equities

I am looking for a source of historical (more than one year) short interest in a specific equity. NASDAQ provides only one year of short interest history. I am interested in looking back 2 to 3 years. Thanks.

Comment: Does the data source need to be free?

Comment: If you have access to a Bloomberg Terminal the {SI GO} function will have a longer history of the exchange reported short interest data.

Answer (score 1):

Markit offers short interest data for various securities. You need to pay for that though